# MySql query to get posts with all meta and terms

Tags: posts, custom-field, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to figureout a way to get all fields from wp_post with all of their custom fields and categories in one mysql query. So in one row of the result I should have post fields with their custom fields and terms...

Note that I'm in phpmyadmin and I Don't know the number of custom fields.. .

Comment: Any specific reason why you need this?